# Trying to multiplex voltage reference gives incorrect output

Tags: multiplexer, voltage-reference

I'm trying to make the voltage reference for an INA214 opamp selectable between GND, 4.5V and 10V. I'm using a [CD4051B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b-mil.pdf) multiplexer.

However, the 10V VREF gets pulled down to 5.84V, and I can't figure out why.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f01D7A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CD4051B has:

- INH, Vee, Vss to GND
- C to GND
- A, B to 5V (thus selecting CH3 as output)
- CH3 to GND
- CH1 to D1 output
- CH2 to D2 output
- Output measured by multimeter

Output measures:

- 4.95V when D2 is connected to any pin on the mux
- 0V when D2 is not connected
- 4.54V when B is GND, no matter if A is 5V or GND (D2 is not connected)

which is strange, because CH1 is A=1 B=0.

What is going here? Are the TL431s interfering with the function of the CD4051B, or...?

By the way, am I required to connect the other pins/channels to ground, or can they be floating?

Comment: You don't say what you're powering the CD4051 with. I'm going to guess that it's 5V - in which case the problem is obvious - you can't pass voltages higher than your supply.

Comment: @brhans, I read the following, from the datasheet, as though 4.5V Vcc would allow up to 20V channel input. Am I mistaken?    _"Control of
analog signals up to 20V P-P can be achieved by digital
signal amplitudes of 4.5V to 20V (if V DD -V SS = 3V, a
V DD -V EE of up to 13V can be controlled; for V DD -V EE level
differences above 13V, a V DD -V SS of at least 4.5V is
required). For example, if V DD = +4.5V, V SS = 0V, and
V EE = -13.5V, analog signals from -13.5V to +4.5V can be
controlled by digital inputs of 0V to 5V."_

Comment: But maybe this is only for signals of negative voltage?

Comment: Look at table 6.1. Maximum input voltage is VDD+0.5 V (to avoid damage, no promise of normal operation in this case).

Comment: That part of the datasheet is referring to your *control inputs* A & B. The specs tell you that your signal inputs cannot exceed your supply.

Comment: Also - that particular case is worded in just the right way "20V **P-P**". The only way to achieve this with a 5V Vcc is by using a Vee of around  -15V and having your analog inout signal swinging between +5V and -15V.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now the 10V VREF isn't pulled down anymore, but the mux is no longer responsive on the ABC pins. I guess I broke it. Good thing it's soldered down well :D

Comment: I've generally learned to ignore anything in a datasheet which looks like it was written by someone in the marketing dept and focus on the tables, figures & diagrams ...

Comment: Not necesseraly @user95482301, logic levels change with supply voltage. AT 10V supply high is >7V.

Comment: @Trevor, I see. I thought it was logic level: _"Logic-Level Conversion for Digital Addressing Signals of 3V to 20V"_? To be honest, I'm not sure how to read this datasheet.

Comment: @user95482301 yes it is one of the more bewildering ones. You probably didn't blow it up though with that 1K resistor above the reference.

Comment: I think this supports what you were saying? _"The ADDRESS (digital-control inputs) and INHIBIT logic levels
are: “0” = Vss and “1” = Vdd"_

Comment: Yes, you will need voltage translation. I suggest using simple NPN transistors as open collector, with pullup resistors.

Comment: Ya pity the translation is not the other way around...

Comment: Or ditch the device entirely and sum in the references to your opamp with mosfets to turn on the one you want.

Comment: It's responding to 12V as signal input, so I think the problem is solved.

Comment: Still, your component count is probably overkill for the problem in hand now.

Comment: @Trevor, Could you post an answer about the MOSFET method? Or a link to a circuit? Not sure what to search for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, issue has to do with supply voltage to device and fixing that screws with the logic levels requiring additional components which makes the rationale for using the device itself suspect.

**Alternative:** Use two low RdsON MOSFETS to change the bias on the TL431 and or short the reference to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFRQJc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is R5 necessary? Without it, wouldn't D1 just be bereaved of its supply? And this would also lower the output impedance?

Comment: @user95482301, I added that to drop the current a little, figured you were using batteries like everyone else these days seems to be. I was assuming high impedance input to your op-amp so it should not matter. But is safe to remove it otherwise.